# The end position of SKNode is not always correct after follow path action finished

Tags: path, sprite-kit

I have a tvOS App which has a SpriteKit node and want to move it in a half circle path. Here is what I do:

```
let alphaAction = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1.0, duration: 3)
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), radius: 500, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
let group = SKAction.group([ alphaAction, SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 3) ])
node?.run(group, completion: {
    print("node: \(self.node?.position)")
})
```

Sometimes the node ends at the right position (-500, 0), but sometimes it ends at (-500, 3.86), (-487, 10.3)...

Anyone knows why this happened and how to solve it ?

Comment: You are dealing with floating point math and inconsistent time frames

Comment: Plus you are doing it when the "group" ends.  the group completion may fire before the follow action finishes.  Try and print the position at a later time to see if you still have your inconsistent numbers.

Comment: I am adding the print statement because the node is not stopped at the right location. Is there any way to make sure the node will stop at (-500, 0) after follow path action ends ?

Comment: Yes, create a sequence and place a moveto action after your path action

Comment: That works. But the final moveto action looks not smoothing.... No way to make sure the follow path will stop at (-500, 0) ?